# Using Ratchet2 alongside Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ratchet-2

I want to use [Ratchet2](http://goratchet.com/) with Bootstrap.  I mainly just want Ratchet two for its badges, its push functionality, and perhaps its icons.

Obviously, I am trying to create a webapp that looks and feels like a native one.

However, I want to continue using my base bootstrap code.  I have looked over the Ratchet documentation, and it seems like Bootstrap and Ratchet will not work together because many of their class names collide.

Was wondering if anyone has tried to accomplish what I intend to do.  Namely, has anyone tried to incorporate only some aspects of ratchet?  How did it work out?  Anything to look out for as I go about this task?

Comment: I used bootstrap first and later used jquery mobile to give my web app more mobile feel. But I got disappointed because bootstrap and JQM doesn't work well together. Today I saw Ratchet2 and wonder if it's compatible with Bootstrap. Seeing your words, I got disappointed again... Hope someone can build some plugins for bootstrap to add more mobile feel to it..